# Compare two numeric columns between tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I would like to create a ms sql query two numeric columns (Days Consumed and vs limit day) between tables in ms sql here are my tables...

Table 1

```
Days consumed   case_id       case_deficiency 
1               101           Debris 
5               102           Graffiti
1               103           Not Functioning
```

on Second table I have

Table 1

```
id     limit day     case_deficiency
1      1             Debris
2      3             Graffiti
3      1             Not Functioning
```

I would like to view/show all case_deficiency if already exceeded the limit day.. in this case Graffiti already exceeded the DAY Consumed > Limit day. Hoping for your helping hand on this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to link the tables based on `case_deficiency`.  The rest is just an appropriate `join`.  So:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.case_deficiency = t2.case_deficiency
where t2.limitday < t1.daysconsumed;
```

Comment: I think your relational operator is the wrong way.  OP wants results where the `Days consumed` field has exceeded the `limit day`. Not trying to nitpick, just something I noticed.